# Is there any way to write wherever I want on a SD card in Android?

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-sdcard

I read a lot of thing on Android and SD card since KitKat. But in the end, I could not find a clear global answer so I'm gonna try to get a relevant answer from you guys.

I want to write a file, a text file, on an arbitrary location on the SD card.

Let's focus on Android 6 with this simple example. Write permission is present in the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I have this helper method

```
private void writeFile(File parent)
{
    try
    {
        File f = new File(parent, "test.txt");
        OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(f));
        outputStreamWriter.write("test");
        outputStreamWriter.close();
        Log.i(TAG, "File created : " + f.getAbsolutePath());
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "File write failed", e);
    }
}
```

And in the test Activity :

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23)
{
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[] {
            android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE }, 1);
    }
    else
    {
        File path = getExternalFilesDirs(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)[1];
        writeFile(path);

        path = getExternalFilesDirs(null)[1];
        writeFile(path);

        writeFile(new File("/storage/3635-3533/"));
    }
}
```

/!\ *Yes the path for the 3rd test is hardcoded by retrieving properly the SD card path is not the subject here* /!\

First launch, [permission asked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mM8eq.png), everything is ok (Sorry french device)

Second launch, here is the result

```
10-03 12:40:10.414: I/TESTSDCARD(26006): File created : /storage/3635-3533/Android/data/com.example.testsdcard/files/Pictures/test.txt
10-03 12:40:10.415: I/TESTSDCARD(26006): File created : /storage/3635-3533/Android/data/com.example.testsdcard/files/test.txt
10-03 12:40:10.426: E/TESTSDCARD(26006): File write failed
10-03 12:40:10.426: E/TESTSDCARD(26006): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/3635-3533/test.txt: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
10-03 12:40:10.426: E/TESTSDCARD(26006):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:459)
10-03 12:40:10.426: E/TESTSDCARD(26006):    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:87)
10-03 12:40:10.426: E/TESTSDCARD(26006):    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:72)
10-03 12:40:10.426: E/TESTSDCARD(26006):    at com.example.testsdcard.MainActivity.writeFile(MainActivity.java:61)
10-03 12:40:10.426: E/TESTSDCARD(26006):    at com.example.testsdcard.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:50)
10-03 12:40:10.426: E/TESTSDCARD(26006):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6367)
10-03 12:40:10.426: E/TESTSDCARD(26006):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
10-03 12:40:10.426: E/TESTSDCARD(26006):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2397)
10-03 12:40:10.426: E/TESTSDCARD(26006):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2504)
10-03 12:40:10.426: E/TESTSDCARD(26006):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:165)
10-03 12:40:10.426: E/TESTSDCARD(26006):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1368)
10-03 12:40:10.426: E/TESTSDCARD(26006):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-03 12:40:10.426: E/TESTSDCARD(26006):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
10-03 12:40:10.426: E/TESTSDCARD(26006):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5546)
10-03 12:40:10.426: E/TESTSDCARD(26006):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-03 12:40:10.426: E/TESTSDCARD(26006):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)
10-03 12:40:10.426: E/TESTSDCARD(26006):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:684)
10-03 12:40:10.426: E/TESTSDCARD(26006): Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
10-03 12:40:10.426: E/TESTSDCARD(26006):    at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
10-03 12:40:10.426: E/TESTSDCARD(26006):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
10-03 12:40:10.426: E/TESTSDCARD(26006):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:445)
10-03 12:40:10.426: E/TESTSDCARD(26006):    ... 16 more
```

As you can see, both tests using `getExternalFilesDirs` work (not surprised, it is supposed to)
But the 3rd one, trying to write at the root of the SD card, failed.

Am i doing it wrong ? Is there any way to perform this action ? Hopefully without using the Storage Access Framework which would be a real pain for me in my app context.

Beside, does the Storage Access Framework allow to perform every basic operation on file (write, delete, rename...) without a huge amount of code ?

Comment: Without root, you don't have write access to `/storage`

Comment: You meant the SD card ?

Comment: Well, some devices don't have an "SD card", so I just mean that path on the filesystem

Comment: I don't really want to write on `/storage`, just write files on SD card like ES file explorer or Solid Explorer. In my example, `/storage/3635-3533/` is the path to my SD card.

Comment: Gotcha. I assumed `3635-3533` was some made-up value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to write a file, a text file, on an arbitrary location on the SD card.

This is not possible on devices that ship with Android 4.4+, except perhaps on rooted devices.

> Write permission is present in the manifest

That permission is for external storage. External storage is not removable storage.

> Am i doing it wrong ?

Yes, insofar as you do not have read/write access to arbitrary locations on removable storage.

> does the Storage Access Framework allow to perform every basic operation on file (write, delete, rename...) without a huge amount of code ?

Nobody but you knows what you would consider "a huge amount of code" to be. Generally speaking, if you have permission from the user for a piece of content (or its container), you can perform the sorts of operations that you see on `DocumentFile`.

Comment: So how come file managers can perform such operations without root access ? They all used the DocumentFile method ?

Comment: @ToYonos: You would have to ask the developers of those specific apps. Note that file managers that ship with the device usually are granted direct access to removable storage.

Comment: I made some test with `DocumentFile` and it does work for file creation/modification. I guess some serious refactoring is expected :)

Comment: I made a confusion between Permission system introduced in Android 6 and the  Storage Access Framework. Using DocumentFile and giving the permission to the right uri, fixed my issue. Thanks for the tip.